# Using patrol test package for google sign in during integration test error

Tags: flutter, google-signin, flutter-integration-test, flutter-patrol

[image: unable to click on the email using Patrol test]

I am unable to select the particular email for google sign-in for testing

this is the error that im facing.

> _AssertionError ('package:patrol/src/custom_finders/patrol_tester.dart': Failed assertion: line 131 pos 7: 'nativeAutomator != null': NativeAutomator is not initialized. Make sure you passed `nativeAutomation: true` to patrolTest(), and that you're *not* initializing any bindings in your test.)

this is the code snippet

```dart
void main() {
  patrolTest(
    'signs up',
    (PatrolTester $) async {
      IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      configureDependencies(testing: true);
      // runZoneGuarded(() => runApp(MyApp));
      await $.pumpWidget(const MyApp());

      final getStartedButton = find.byKey(const Key("getStartedButton"));
      await $.tap(getStartedButton);
      await $.pumpAndSettle();
      await $('LOGIN WITH GOOGLE').tap();
      await $.native.tap(Selector(text: 'Neel Kothari'));
      await $.pumpAndSettle();
    },
    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Patrol's [native automation](https://patrol.leancode.co/native/overview) feature, you have to set the `nativeAutomation` argument to `true` in call to `patrolTest()`:

```dart
void main() {
  patrolTest(
    'signs up',
    nativeAutomation: true,
    (PatrolTester $) async {
      // test code 
    },
  );
}
```

BTW, don't call `IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` – Patrol has its own binding which is already initialized at this point, and calling this line will conflict with Patrol's binding.